# Formula to compare two dates plus a value cell in order to see if its correct or no. (example in pic)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, excel-2016

example:

[image]

If the Date is equal or later than today, value should be different than $0.00.

If the Date is before today, value should be equal to $0.00.

Answer (score 0):

A simple if.  Put this in C2 and copy down.

```
=IF(OR(AND(A2<$D$2,B1=0),AND(A2>=$D$2,B1<>0)),"Check","Error")
```